# Are these two questions related？

Tags: analysis, supremum-and-infimum

$f$ and $g$ are bounded functions with common domain$D$

$\sup\limits_{x\in D}\big\{f(x)+g(x)\big\}\leqslant\sup\limits_{x\in D}f(x)+\sup\limits_{x\in D}g(x).$

Let both $S $and $T$ be non-empty subsets of $R$

$S+T=\begin{Bmatrix}z & \mid z=s+t,s\in S,t\in T\end{Bmatrix}.$
$\sup(S+T)=\sup S+\sup T$
What I want to know is, are these two issues related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\text{Im}(f + g) = \left\{f(x) + g(x) ~|~ x \in D\right\} \subseteq \text{Im}(f) + \text{Im}(g) = \left\{f(x) + g(y) ~|~ x,y \in D\right\}.$$
That's why you have an inequality
\begin{align}
\sup\limits_{x\in D}\big\{f(x)+g(x)\big\} &= \sup\text{Im}(f + g)\\
&\le \sup \left(\text{Im}(f) + \text{Im}(g)\right)\\
&= \sup \text{Im}(f) + \sup \text{Im}(g)\\
& = \sup\limits_{x\in D}f(x)+\sup\limits_{x\in D}g(x)
\end{align}